# UITableviewcell accessoryview disaapears after UIActivityIndicatorView plays in tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am parsing some data in my view, while that is happening I have a uitableviewcell that has a accessoryview, the activityindicator replaces this accessory view while the data is being parsed.

After the parsing is done and the activityindicatorview disaapears the accessory view never comes back. Is there something I can call to get it to appear again? or any other ideas?

I don't think I need to post any code but if you need it I will do that I'm just hoping its something dumb that I have missed.

Any help would greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set the `accessoryView` to nil.

Comment: at first I was like... to nil? what is he thinking.. Then I was like I better try this.. Finally I was like WhooHOO! that worked! :) haha cheers heaps man.